# Design application architecture for catalog/orders system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, architecture

I have to write a system that allows clients to make orders of products. There is an existing application that handles creating catalog (adding, editing products etc.) It is used by producents to maintain data about their products. Now I am wondering how should I add order functionality (I have access to source code of catalog application and catalog database). Order functionality can be shortly describe as:

- customer can login make new orders, see old ones
- producer can login and see new orders made by clients, archive orders
- midleman should see all orders grouped by producer so he can decide whether or not to ship them

I am thinking about few ways:

**Create new application with new database, that contains only orders.**

- products in catalog database and order database will be connected by [producent_id, product_id] pair
- in orders application I would connect to catalog database to show information about products

  Disadvantages of that approach, that I can think of are

  - not being able to do statistics queries like "count all orders of items from category that are made of wood" etc.

  Advantages

  - clear seperation from existing application

**Add functionality to existing application and use the same database**

- producer has another option in menu "Orders"
- add new functionality for clients and middleman

Disadvantages of that approach, that I can think of are

- not being able to for example move orders database/aplication to another server

Advantages

- able to run cross orders/catalog queries

I really can't make my mind about this. I can see upsides and downsides for both ways, but can't decide which is better. Do you have any suggestions, maybe third way?

P.S technology will be ruby on rails

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go for the 'add functionality to existing application'.

I don't suppose you want to sell the Order application separate because it totally depends on how your Catalog/Product app is build.

The development will  be easier, not only database access but also the reuse of the existing infrastructure will improve your development speed.

I suppose the only reason you want to move the orders application to another server is because of performance problems. I would say that you should never optimize for a situation your not sure it will ever happen.

It's much harder to do cross database queries which are not supported then to optimize the application when you notice some real, measurable, performance issues.

So in my opinion development speed out wages supposed performance problems.

Comment: i'm also worried about situation like this: i make some huge changes to existing code but not ready for production and then we will have to make some changes to catalog... Do you think creating svn brunch will be good way to solve this?

Comment: Yes! Branching will definitely help. If you do all the new development in branches (and possibly subbranches) you can always release a new version of the existing application without problems. Could you keep the old code completely ignorant of the new code? That would probably improve your design.

Comment: I suppose I can, but still I would like to avoid putting in production code that cannot be used (that would be the case without branching) On the other hand searching for svn branch/merge gives pretty scarry results - lots of complains about this functionality in svn...

Comment: I'm no expert on SVN but branching is such a common thing in Source Control that I would always advice to use it. When doing new development combined with supporting older releases it will make your life much easier.

Comment: Ok, I will look into it. Thanks for your engagement :)